# Spring @ControllerAdvice redirect

Tags: spring, annotations

I have a spring-mvc application with a `ControllerAdvice` annotation, is it possible for me to redirect  to a page from there? i mean, with the `@controller` if i do something like `return "home\homepage"` and Spring send me to the home page, I need something to do the same within the `@ControllerAdvice`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: return "home\homepage" means returning a view not a redirect, do you still want to redirect?

Comment: Sry for now answering earlier, i would like to return a view, is that possible from a controller advice?

Comment: I think that you should make a method with ModelAndView but I'm unable to check in the docs right now because of the poor mobile connection. I will get back to you later today.